# How to remove a bugged device from the android emulators list

Tags: android, flutter

I have an invalid device that appeared recently in my emulator list, but it doesn't show up in my virtual device manager.

It looks like this:

```
"INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\flutt\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 1132'
```

It shows up both in vscode and android studio as an android emulator device, but it is not a runnable device and will give this error if I try to run it:

```
"Failed to launch INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\flutt\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 8744: emulator 'INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\flutt\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 8744' not found"
```

I already checked the avd folder where the virtual machines for emulators are stored, but there is nothing unusual.

I also tried deleting all virtual devices and create them again, but this buggy one called "INFO" still remains.

How can I remove it from the list of devices?

Comment: Uninstall this data otherwise, Try to create new device.

Comment: @ZeelkumarSojitra that's what I'm asking, how can I delete it

Comment: the mentioned folder is autogenerated, deleting does not remove the device from the list and is recreated if I try to run the device

Comment: Open android studio -> go to device manager (to showing right hand side) -> click to create new -> and create new device as your needs.

Comment: @ZeelkumarSojitra As I already stated in the question, that has already been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install version 33.1.24 of emulator using this instruction https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive and the error in the device list will disappear. Maybe some other version will work.